# Creating an adjacency matrix from a cell array

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, image-segmentation

I'm going to create an adjacency matrix from a cell array, but faced two main problems:

1. I don't know how to access to cell array's elements; so an adhoc method was used.
2. (and the most important) The code produces an error and the partial result is also a weird one!

The cell array is as the following image:
[image: screen shot of MATLAB's variable editor showing the contents of a cell array]

The code is as follows:

```
for i=1:N
    L=size(Al{i});
    Len=L(1,2);
    for j=1:Len
        elm=Al{i};
        D=elm(i,j);
        Adjm(i,D)=1;
    end
end
```

The code produces this error:

[image: screen shot of the MATLAB command window showing an error message]

and the output is as follows:
[image: yet another screen shot showing defined variables]

P.S.: The code is part of a program to construct adjacency matrix to represent superpixels adjacency within an image. There may be a specific solution for that!

Comment: I don't understand... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55085475/7328782) you got code that creates the adjacency matrix. `glcms` in that code is an adjacency matrix. All you need to do is `Adjm = glcms` and you're done. Why do you need to do all of this?

Comment: Also, "I don't know how to access to cell array's elements; so an adhoc method was used." You are indexing `Al{i}`, that is not an adhoc method, that is the normal and correct method to get the contents of a cell in a cell array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, OMG!, I forgot about that .  I was looking for a method such as the submitted answer. By the way, thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways your code could be made better, but the specific error you are seeing is because you want `D=elm(1,j);` instead of `D=elm(i,j);`. Note the `1` instead of `i`.

A somewhat more efficient approach would be to do,

```
for i=1:numel(Al)
    Adjm(i,Al{i})=1;
end
```

As with your code, this assumes that there are no empty elements in `Al`.